# How to read bullet list from word file using microsoft.interop.word?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on a c# project (.Net 4.0) where we are extracting data from word file using microsoft's interop assembly. I have read bold, italic, underline etc. Now I want to read bullet list from word file. How can I do this using interop?